# Jest does not wait for fileStream "finish" callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, jestjs

I am using `Jest` to read a bunch of CSV files and check for validation. However, even with the `done` parameter, it gives me:

```
    Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.

      at node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queue_runner.js:68:21
      at Timeout.callback [as _onTimeout] (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js:633:19)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        13.682s
```

Sample code:

```
describe('Validate there are no duplicates', () => {
    it('Read and validate CSV files', done => {
        parseCSVs((err, result) => {
            if(err) {
                return done(err)
            }
            console.log(result)
            expect(result.idSet.size).toBe(result.validationCounter)
            done()
        })
    })
});
```

Function which is called:

```
parseCSVs = (callback) => {
    let validationCounter = 0
    const idSet = new Set([])
        for (const someNumber of setOfNumbers.keys()) {
            const fullDest = baseDir + "/Client" + someNumber
            Filehound.create()
            .ext('csv')
            .paths(fullDest)
            .find((err, csvFiles) => {
                if (err) {
                    callback(err, null)
                    return
                } else {
                    for (file of csvFiles) {
                        const csvFileStream = fs.createReadStream(file);
                        csv()
                        .fromStream(csvFileStream)
                        .on("json", (jsonObj) => {
                            const validationID = Object.values(jsonObj).toString().split(';')[2]
                            idSet.add(validationID)
                            validationCounter++
                        })
                        .on("finish", () => {
                            callback(null, {validationCounter, idSet}) // Why doesn't it let this async operation finish?
                        })
                    }
                }
            });
        }
}
```

On the fileStream, I await the "finish" for each file and then return the callback. However, even with the `done` added to the test, it exits after five seconds due to no callback. Why is that? Can I not do async operations in Jest with a waiting time over 5 seconds?

Comment: You probably need to increase your [test timeout](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/652#issuecomment-330372906). This is besides the question but in general you should [avoid long-running unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10513/1814486).

Comment: Seems like you're right, trying with setting `jest.setTimeout(1000000)` before my test runs.. Crossing fingers!